# Choosing companies from a dataframe with monthl returns based on company list of other dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multipleselection

I'm currently writing my master thesis and I would like to calculate the portfolio returns for a list of companies. Therefore, I want to choose the companies from the dataframe with their monthly returns. I want to select the companies, which are in another dataframe.
The dataframe with the returns looks like that:
[image: monthlyreturns]

The second dataframe with the company names according to which I want to choose, looks like that:
[image]

I tried something like this:
`mrt.loc[mrt['Company Name'] == SL1['Company Name']]`, which just gives me the Error 'Company Name'. I checked and the spelling should be correct.
I tried as well this:

```
mrt.loc[mrt == SL0['Company Name']]
```

This gives me a list of companies but I need as well the monthlyreturns from the dataframe mrt.

So as a recap I want the rows from mrt according to the company names in the dataframe SL0. And I need to do this afterwards with other dataframes like SL0 but with different length.

Could someone help? Thank you very much and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

`isin()` would resolve this issue.

```
df
###
  Company Name  value1
0        Apple       1
1       Google       2
2    Microsoft       3
3     Facebook       4
4        Tesla       5
5       Amazon       6
6     Alphabet       7
7       Oracle       8
8          IBM       9
9     Facebook      10
```

```
df2
###
   value2  value3 Company Name
0      51      11        Apple
1      52      22       Google
2      35      33    Microsoft
3      54      44     Facebook
```

Selecting

```
df[df['Company Name'].isin(df2['Company Name'])]
###
  Company Name  value1
0        Apple       1
1       Google       2
2    Microsoft       3
3     Facebook       4
9     Facebook      10
```